# Xamarin.forms C# 2 quotation marks

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to format this line of code so that in "myusername" you can enter the text typed from the phone keyboard, e.g. instead of "myusername" I would like there to be email.Text. email.text must be in quotation marks. Sorry for my bad english.

```
string jsonData = @"{""username"" : ""myusername"", ""password"" : ""mypassword""}";
```

I tried this way but it still doesn't work

```
 string jsonData = "{ \"Email\" : \"{0}\" ,\"Password\" : \"{1}\"}";

 string jsonMain = String.Format(jsonData, email.Text, password.Text);
```

Comment: create a C# class and serialize it to json instead of trying to manually build a json string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Serializing and Deserializing JSON` with follow codes:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        testModel model = new testModel();
        model.Email = "abc";
        model.username = "allen";

        string jsonString;
        jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

        //deserialize
        testModel deserializedmodel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<testModel>(jsonString);

    }
}

public class testModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}
```